# React application working on desktop but showing a blank page on mobile

Tags: heroku, mobile, create-react-app

This issue has nothing to do with [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39826101/react-application-works-on-desktop-but-on-mobile-a-blank-page-is-shown).

I built a full-stack application using create-react-app, Express, and MongoDB. [As you can see](https://project-pyrope.herokuapp.com/), I successfully deployed it on Heroku (no errors in the log). The root ("/") page is supposed to be empty for now.

The problem arises when I try to access the application with my phone (iPhone 5s): I get this blank page, whether I am using Chrome, Firefox, or Safari:

[image: Blank page on iPhone 5s]

I should be able to see the navbar, even though the page has no content. A friend of mine uses an Android phone, and he got the same result.

It doesn't seem like there's a problem with the responsiveness since I can see the navbar with Chrome's developer tools:

[image]

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

I realized I was using Redux Devtools in production also. The error was caused by the fact that I was seeing the application with browsers that didn't have the extension installed.

Comment: finally, are you able to work it on your phone or not? if yes please reply how you did so. :)

Comment: I shared the reason why it didn't work in my last comment.

Comment: Yes, I got it. Because of redux Dev tools, but how to remove it from code? Without affecting other running components?

Comment: On the client side, you can detect whether or not Node is running in development, and only then initialize Redux Devtools.

Comment: thanks, I think now I am not further developing that project, so the need of development env, so I am going to remove Redux Devtools. or should I check first then disable redux-devtools? BTW I am also following MERN stack course from Brad traversy sir, same as you.

Comment: I have removed redux-dev-tools, and then pushed to heroku but still it won't work on mobile. https://github.com/ganesh-deshmukh/connect-geeks/commit/62bcb8dfbda1d693c8e497c58ab8de8ed8727f74

Comment: I have the same issue please help me to solve it on SO, link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55881971/mern-stack-webapp-showing-blank-screen-android-mobile-browser-as-react-redux-fr

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but I'll post the answer in case anyone needs it.

The problem is in your server.js (Backend) file.
You need to put the middlewares in **server.js** in the following order.

[Screenshot to show the order of the middlewares](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9FSM6.png)

Answer (score 0):

As jsrobertouimet explains this is caused by seeing your app with Redux Devtools.

In my case my Store was still with Devtools

```
    const store = createStore(
      rootReducer, 
      compose(applyMiddleware(thunk),
      window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && 
      window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__())
    );
```

To solve this I just deleted Redux Devtools extension code

```
    const store = createStore(
      rootReducer, 
      compose(applyMiddleware(thunk))
    );
```

Also delete the Redux Devtools extension in your browser to see as in your phone or any other device.