# MERN stack webapp showing blank screen Android-mobile browser, as React-Redux frontend, Node-Express backend

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-devtools

I have built up WebApp in MERN stack with MongoDB, Express, React, Nodejs.

I hosted it to Heroku-Cloud as https://connectgeeks.herokuapp.com.

[Github-repo](https://github.com/ganesh-deshmukh/connect-geeks/commits/master) of the project- Find_Geeks.
it works on my Desktop browsers but can't run on any Android chrome.

I have an auto-build app in Heroku cloud with command in package.json as

`"scripts:{
"heroku-postbuild": "NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix frontend && npm run build --prefix frontend"
}`

when it loads on android, it's search bar background changes to black and I assume the page is loaded that time, but can't display components.

Screenshot of Desktop-chrome, in the working state.

[image: screenshot1]

Screenshot of Desktop-chrome, in Incognito-mode, the working state.

[image: screenshot2]

Screenshot of Mobile-mode in chrome, the working state.

[image: screenshot3]

my `package.json` contents are

```
{
  "name": "find-geeks",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "social media for developers, quite same as Linkedin.",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "client-install": "npm install --prefix frontend",
    "start": "node server.js",
    "server": "nodemon server.js",
    "client": "npm start --prefix frontend",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client  \"",
    "heroku-postbuild": "NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix frontend && npm run build --prefix frontend"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/ganesh-deshmukh/connect-geeks.git"
  },
  "author": "Ganesh Ashok Deshmukh",
  "license": "MIT",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/ganesh-deshmukh/connect-geeks/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/ganesh-deshmukh/connect-geeks#readme",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcryptjs": "2.4.3",
    "body-parser": "1.18.2",
    "concurrently": "3.5.1",
    "express": "4.16.3",
    "gravatar": "1.6.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "8.2.0",
    "mongoose": "5.4.0",
    "passport": "0.4.0",
    "passport-jwt": "4.0.0",
    "validator": "9.4.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "1.17.3"
  }
}
```

Edit 1:

I tried debugging on mobile screen via localhost-server, at url `http://192.168.43.171:3000/`,

[image: screenshot5]

then it showed error location as,

[image: screen6]

[image: screen7]

[image: screen8]

Removed DevTools from store.js, and now it works on Mobile browsers, through localhost-server.

[image: screen8]

maybe that's due to Heroku-build script or any other.

it works on a mobile screen just after removing redux-dev-tools, as this locally.

but it won't work with URL as https://connectgeeks.herokuapp.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this question doesn't have any error but the mistake of not pushing Heroku master once changes were done.

I checked logs on Heroku dashboard, and it showed activity at old-date, though I updated and push git-repo.

my mistake was not pushing Heroku-repo after removing redux-dev-tools.

after solving it, in the activity tab, it shows new logs, means it's updated.

[image: screen1]

It works on mobile now, both through localhost-server and url as https://connect-geeks.herokuapp.com/

[image: screen2]

Comment: also, I changed app's url from `connect-geeks` to `connectgeeks`.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I'll post the answer in case anyone needs it.

The problem is in your server.js (Backend) file.
You need to put the middlewares in **server.js** in the following order.

[order of the middlewares](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nPeoS.png)